# Dockerfile for building an HTTP triggered Azure Function App not working

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, dockerfile

I struggle with creating a Docker file for an HTTP triggered Azure Function App. I have enabled Docker Support in Visual Studio for the Function App project, but obviously the Dockerfile created is not suitable for an Function app that is HTTP triggered.

I have working Dockerfiles for time triggered Function Apps - but as far as I understand the HTTP triggered ones are entirely different. I understand I might have to use a different base image, and it looks as if on container startup I need to launch the Azure Functions Host by running

```
CMD dotnet /azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll
```

However, I did not find a working example, and also MS documentation looks poor.

Using different sources and previous questions on SO I came up with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs 
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CdWebHook/CdWebHook.csproj", "CdWebHook/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CdWebHook/CdWebHook.csproj"
COPY ["MyCmpOps/MyCmpOps.csproj", "MyCmpOps/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyCmpOps/MyCmpOps.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/CdWebHook"
RUN dotnet build "CdWebHook.csproj" -c Release -o /home/site/wwwroot/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CdWebHook.csproj" -c Release -o /home/site/wwwroot/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=publish /home/site/wwwroot .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
CMD dotnet /azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll
```

When trying to start it locally or on Azure, I get this error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "/azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost": stat
> /azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: no such
> file or directory: unknown.

Which makes me believe that I am using the wrong base container that does not provide the Azure functions host - or I need to install it somehow. I'm building the Dockerfile with a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps - which works fine, no obvious errors in the process.

I found this [page about base images](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-base) basically linking to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-custom-container?tabs=acr%2Cazure-cli&pivots=azure-functions), but it lacks some example Dockerfile.

Any suggestions on how to make this Dockerfile work with Azure?

Comment: You're specifying the wrong path to run, and it's telling you it can't find the file specified. You're setting `WORKDIR` to `/home`/, copying files into `/home/site/wwwroot`, then trying to run `/azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll`. You should be running your function app assembly out of the `/home/site/wwwroot` location.